# Keeping references between parent and children

Tags: vb.net, parent-child

I would like to write a class that acts like a collection of items, and make it take care of a  reference of the objects added to itself. Just like a TreeNode in this example:

```
    Dim father As New TreeNode("Father")
    Dim son As New TreeNode("Son")
    father.Nodes.Add(son)

    Dim p As TreeNode = son.Parent 'p is father

    father.Nodes.Clear()

    p = son.Parent  'p is Nothing
```

I thought about establishing the reference in "Son" to the "Father" in the Add method, and removing it in the Remove and Clear methods. However, sinde the Parent property is ReadOnly, I cannot change it, so... how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for info on doing this with CLASSES as in the first sentence or with CONTROLS as in the code and rest of the question?

Comment: It seems that you're trying to re-invent the wheel.  What are you trying to do that you can't use the existing TreeNode or TreeNodeCollection classes?  If necessary you can use them as private properties then use public methods to manipulate them.  This how the Parent property gets changed even though it is ReadOnly

Comment: I want to create two classes that have this behaviour, I used the TreeNode example only to present an example of what I would want those classes to do. 
I haven't thought about the posibility of using TreeNodes as private fileds for providing this behaviour, thanks for the suggestion, I will try to use it.